# Performance of Consumption-hosted Functions on Azure free subscriptions

Tags: c#, azure, scalability, azure-functions

I am evaluating Azure Functions using Azure Free Trial Subscription.
Everything is OK except for performance/scalability.

I developed trivial http-triggered function (C# Class library), that does nothing but sleeps 5 seconds.
When executed once, directly, it works like 5s, exactly as expected. 
But when called 500 times in parallel - execution time grows up to 20-30 seconds.

Function is "hosted" on Consumption plan, so I expected that once required, it is executed on separate VM "automatically". 
I checked ARR Cookies (that might have stuck my requests to one VM) - no, no 
cookies at all.
Everything looks fine, at least for such simple case (no obvious bottlenecks to check - no DB, no communications, etc.).

So, the question is - is it because of free trial subscription, or I am missing something?

Comment: I contacted Azure support team (via chat here https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free/free-account-faq/) and asked this question. Answer was that Free Trial Subscription has resource limitations and to provide proof of scalability I will be contacted by Azure tech specialists who will help me with it. Will keep track of it here.

Comment: That answer from support is not correct - you will get dynamic scaling in Consumption plan in your free trial sub. I just did my own quick test and for 500 parallel requests and a 5 second async sleep (await Task.Delay(5000)) in an async function, I see similar latencies. The issue comes down to the fact that for an instantaneous spike of requests like this our scale out logic is failing to scale out fast enough - all requests hit the single instance. We're working on improvements that will be released soon that will allow us to burst scale in cases like this.

Comment: @mathewc, thanks! Is there any way to pre-configure minimum number of instances, or, so-to-say, "warm-up" the function app on consumption plan?

Comment: No at this time, Dmitry. You'd have to warm it up yourself by doing a pre-load on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference for Azure Functions on Free Trial Subscriptions. You aren't being slowed down by that.

As @mathewc pointed out, this is due to HTTP scale out having some lag which we're working to improve. You can see some knobs you can control here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/wiki/Http-Functions#throttling

If you enable throttling, it will result in 429s, but will help prevent increasing execution times.